# Open bootstrap dropdown on input focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, bootstrap-4, backbone-views

I have an input that when clicked shows a bootstrap 4 dropdown BUT I need it to open when a user tabs to it as well for ADA accessibility.

If I use a focus event that uses $('#input-name).dropdown('toggle') it works fine, but when the input is clicked focus fires first which opens the dropdown and then the click event closes it.

I have tried e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();  but neither help solve this issue.

```
events: {
  focus #healthPlanMenu": "openDropDown"
}


openDropDown: function (e) {

  if ($('#healthPlanMenu').find('.dropdown-menu:no(.show)')){
    $("#healthPlanMenu.dropdown-toggle").dropdown('toggle');
   }//fails

    $("#healthPlanMenu.dropdown-toggle").dropdown('toggle');//fails
    $( "#healthPlanMenu" ).click();//fails

  }
```

Comment: "I need it to open when a user tabs to it" seems like an anti-pattern, because tab is just supposed to select a dropdown, not open it. You need to press enter in order to open it. Huge dropdowns opening while tabbing to some other element on a form will be annoying. What will happen If a blind person who is familiar with standard dropdowns tabs and presses enter ? (Normal dropdowns will close if already opened).

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but in this case this is the ideal scenario for a blind user and what this solution is for. It is a complex dropdown, but not a huge one where a plan and a product have to be chosen to help the user get the right results for them. Selecting only a plan will result in an error state that is announce and focused properly for the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So ideally you'd probably solve this by having the `focus` event set the dropdown's state to open, that way if it gets "reopened" by the click event, no problem.  However, as far as I can tell there is only a `toggle` option with the jQuery API; seems unnecessarily limiting...

Given that, we can know if a click is coming after our focus event by using `mousedown`.  So a somewhat hacky way to solve this problem is to disable our focus event if we know a click is coming.

```js
(function() {
 var disable = false;
 $('#healthPlanMenu.dropdown-toggle')
  .on('mousedown touchstart', function() {
   disable = true;
  })
  .on('focus', function() {
   if (!disable) {
    $(this).dropdown('toggle');
   }
  })
  .on('mouseup touchend',function() {
   disable = false;
  })
})()
```

I don't know if the `touchstart` and `touchend` are necessary as most browsers probably fire mouse events on touch as well.  But better safe than sorry.